# Can a.X.com CNAME a.Y.com

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, cross-domain

I believe similar questions have already been answered. But my knowledge on network is sooo poor that I cannot even tell the similarity.

I work for X and we use Y's SaaS Application. The application is at **a.Y.com**.
But we do not want users to use a.Y.com. We want them to use **a.X.com** all the time and **make a.Y.com invisible**. But my coworkers at Network team say they can only do a URL redirect because a.Y.com is not within X's network. Is it true? Wikipedia mentions something about CName. Is CName the solution if it is no true?

Comment: A CNAME record will get them there but if there is an absolute path anywhere on the site that will put a.y.com into the user's address bar again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CNAME should work the way you want it to as long as the application is not accessed using TLS/SSL, and uses relative rather than absolute URIs for its internal links. But a SaaS application certainly *should* use TLS, and if it does then you'll get a certificate name mismatch warning in the browser, since the certificate will be for a.y.com (or *.y.com) and not for a.x.com.

Comment: The SaaS application does use TLS 1.2. Can users skip the warning in IE, Safari and Firefox? -- added: I think yes they can but user experience will be terrible. Can A-name or Alias pass the warning but still works the way I want?

Comment: The `CNAME` happens at the DNS level and so `http` wouldn't realize this was happening.  If you want to deal with this at the http level skip the `CNAME` and do a redirect from one domain to another.

Comment: Redirect is what we are using now. i don't like it but it seems it is the best option. Many thanks to all of you!!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this problem that I can think of would be to have a full screen `<iframe>` on a.X.com that loads a.Y.com. Note that this will break bookmarking, so you may want to consider the pros and cons.